# myEclipse preference does not have maven options

Tags: java, maven, myeclipse

I'm new to myeclipse here.
And when I tried to import a project builted with myEclipse 2017 CI10 as long as its maven support, I found my same version ME do not have any maven options in preference.
However, my colleagues used windows for this software while I'm using MacOS.But I dont think it will cause these problems.Can any one help me with that?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be running MyEclipse, from that screenshot. It shows no MyEclipse capabilities or preferences at all. It's possible that an attempt to install a plugin has given you the option of uninstalling MyEclipse (or many MyEclipse components) and you inadvertently accepted that option. There are other pointers in your sreenshot which suggest that this is not a proper MyEclipse install. Regarding Maven, note the "Maven Repositories" view is in your screenshot, suggesting that the workspace was created with an eclipse that has the maven plugin.

If you are running MyEclipse, adding, to your question, the output from Help->Installation Summary->Installation details (not the output accessible through the About dialog) might give us some more clues. If you don't have Installation Summary under the help menu then that is another indication that you aren't running MyEclipse.